# ObjectProxy to TextFlow (html) in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, proxy, flex4, flex4.7

I'm trying to convert a ProxyObject into a TextFlow so I can output in a RichText.
I'm recieving the ProxyObject trough a http-request.

```
<s:HTTPService id="httpStoryDetail" url="{urlDetails}"/>
```

The service gots to a php-script with the output as follows:

```
<user>username</user>
<story><p>Here some text which has <b>html</b> tags.<p><story>
```

I'm trying to fetch the story so I can bind it to a RichText but that needs a TextFlow.
How do I do that? Or is there a better option for doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need get string from your HTTPService, for example you get string "`<p>Here some text which has <b>html</b> tags.<p>`"
After that you will be able to set this string to RichText.

```
//Must be your string
var richText:String = "<p fontSize=\"10\">A small normal paragraph</p>" +
    "<p fontSize=\"14\" fontWeight=\"bold\">A medium bold paragraph</p>" +
    "<p fontSize=\"18\">A large<span fontStyle=\"italic\">mixed-text paragraph</span></p>"

myRichText.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(
    richText, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE);
```